# Plotting 2D function of two variables

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
g(x, y) = x * (y + 3) - 5
```

I want a 2D plot of the "points" where x and y are {1, 2, 3 .. 10 }.
How to do this? I could only find 3d plotting.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to plot. If x is 1 and y is 1, tehn g[1,1)=-1. What exactly do you want to plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g[x_, y_] := x*(y + 3) - 5
MatrixPlot[Array[g, {10, 10}], PlotLegends -> Automatic, DataReversed -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, just as I was searching for. Thank you!

Comment: @AfonsoMatos, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 3):

```
g[x_, y_] := x*(y + 3) - 5
```

You could use either [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
ContourPlot[
 g[x, y], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, Contours -> Range[0, 120, 5],
 ContourLabels -> All,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

or [`DensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html)

```
DensityPlot[
 g[x, y], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 MeshFunctions -> (#3 &),
 Mesh -> {Range[0, 120, 5]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
DiscretePlot3D[x (y + 3) - 5, 
    {x, 0, 10}, 
    {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple 2D plot

```
g[x_, y_] := x*(y + 3) - 5
tp = Table[
   Plot[g[x, y], {x, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> {-5, 120}, 
    PlotLabel -> {"y", y}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "g[x,y]"}], {y, 1, 10}];

gifs = ListAnimate[tp]
```

[image]

Alternatively you could plot `g` vs `y` and then vary `x`.